# How to check if location available using FusedLocationProviderApi and GoogleClient?

Tags: android, geolocation

We can check for location availability using Location manager's isProviderEnabled method.
I am trying to use the new api's for location, i.e. fusedLocationProviderApi and trying to check if location can be retrieved.
How to check that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned in your question, You can check if the Provider is enabled by using Location Manager's isProviderEnabled method, like below.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

By using `FusedLocationApi` with `GoogleApiClient` and `LocationRequest`, you can request Location Updates with `LocationListener` Interface which will have a callback method called when the location is changed. `onLocationChanged(Location location)`. So you can know if the location can be granted or not in `onLocationChanged` method.

So an example flow can be; Checking Location providers to see if they are enabled, and then trying to connect to GoogleApiClient to see if the user has GooglePlayServices etc that can get the User's Location.